# How to calcualte RMSE with GridSearchCV.best_score_

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently using the scorer "neg_mean_squared_error" but I want the root mean squared error.

```
randsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=reg, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=n_iter_for_rand, cv=cv_for_rand, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error",verbose=0, n_jobs=-1,refit=True)
```

Can I just fit the data. Then do :

```
math.sqrt(randsearch.best_score_)
```

Or do I need to make a a customer scorer with "sklearn.metrics.make_scorer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just fit the data and take `math.sqrt(-randsearch.best_score_)`.